# Realizar insert de una consulta tras modificarla con SQLalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

La idea es realizar una consulta a la BBDD, modificar los datos que correspondan y luego hacer insert de los datos modificados en lugar de update

ejemplo: una consulta

```
medias.query()

Resultado
╔════╦════════╦════════╦═══════╦═══════════╗
║ id ║ numero ║ nombre ║ media ║ trimestre ║
╠════╬════════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════════╣
║ 1  ║ 1101   ║ Juan   ║ 6     ║ 1         ║
╠════╬════════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════════╣
║ 2  ║ 1102   ║ Carlos ║ 8     ║ 1         ║
╠════╬════════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════════╣
║ 3  ║ 1123   ║ Ana    ║ 7     ║ 1         ║
╠════╬════════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════════╣
║ 4  ║ 914    ║ Sofia  ║ 6     ║ 1         ║
╠════╬════════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════════╣
║ 5  ║ 1150   ║ Ileia  ║ 8     ║ 1         ║
╚════╩════════╩════════╩═══════╩═══════════╝
```

Con esos datos modifico lo que quiero, pero si hago session.commit() me actualiza los datos que ya hay mientras que yo quiero que los inserte

```
Resultado esperado:    
╔════╦════════╦════════╦═══════╦═══════════╗
║ id ║ numero ║ nombre ║ media ║ trimestre ║
╠════╬════════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════════╣
║ 1  ║ 1101   ║ Juan   ║ 6     ║ 1         ║
╠════╬════════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════════╣
║ 2  ║ 1102   ║ Carlos ║ 8     ║ 1         ║
╠════╬════════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════════╣
║ 3  ║ 1123   ║ Ana    ║ 7     ║ 1         ║
╠════╬════════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════════╣
║ 4  ║ 914    ║ Sofia  ║ 6     ║ 1         ║
╠════╬════════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════════╣
║ 5  ║ 1150   ║ Ileia  ║ 8     ║ 1         ║
╠════╬════════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════════╣
║ 6  ║ 1101   ║ Juan   ║ 5     ║ 2         ║
╠════╬════════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════════╣
║ 7  ║ 1102   ║ Carlos ║ 9     ║ 2         ║
╠════╬════════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════════╣
║ 8  ║ 1123   ║ Ana    ║ 8     ║ 2         ║
╠════╬════════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════════╣
║ 9  ║ 914    ║ Sofia  ║ 5     ║ 2         ║
╠════╬════════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════════╣
║ 10 ║ 1150   ║ Ileia  ║ 8     ║ 2         ║
╚════╩════════╩════════╩═══════╩═══════════╝
```

session.add(consulta_modificada) me da error

La única solución que saco de la documentación es generar objetos nuevos por cada linea de la consulta

Notas:

```
Python 3.7 y 3.8
Sqlalchemy 1.13.10
estoy usando mysql

El ejemplo no es de la tabla que quiero modificar, pero lo resume bien
La tabla en la que lo quiero usar tiene unas 23 columnas de las que solo
se modifica UNA que es un id para el conjunto de datos
```